# Is there a way to dynamically change style on a YouTube chromeless player with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I have played around with the chromeless YouTube player API. I am trying to implement a Function that expands the video to a semi-fullscreen view (i.e. to the size of the document body). It seems though that changing style properties such as `position` (to e.g. `fixed`), changing parent style or moving the `Object` `Node` breaks the player (i.e. the player `Object` is still there but it does not expose any methods anymore).

Can anyone confirm and/or shed some light on this behaviour. Any possible work-arounds would be great as well.

---

**Edit**:

The YouTube player `Object` -- in my test case -- is dynamically added as follows:

```
<object 
   width="204" height="114"
   type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
   data="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1" 
   style="visibility: visible; z-index: 1;"
>
       <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
</object>
```

I'm controlling the player using the JavaScript API documented here:

- [YouTube Player JavaScript API documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)

---

TIA,

FK